# Keeping determine digits in Append to process

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

The end of my code is written as below. Ignoring the inefficient role of `Append`, I want to have very simple set of values as for example:
 `{0.70, 0.091, 0.3032},{0.70, 0.094, 0.2933},{0.70, 0.097, 0.2840}.....`

But when I copy and paste `whole` (below code) in another notebook to save them for being protected from unintentional events, unfortunately I encounter to

[image]

However, I don't have problem with this copied format but I want to have no messy output. For example same as `{0.70, 0.091, 0.3032},{0.70, 0.094, 0.2933},{0.70, 0.097, 0.2840}.....`

**Code**

```
.
.
.
AppendTo[whole, {x, y, Round[n,0.0001]}]; 

 , {y, 0.001, 2.0, 0.003}]; 

 , {x, 0, 2, 0.05}]
```

Comment: Hard to understand what exactly you're looking for, but you probably want either `Chop` or `SetPrecision`.

Comment: You probably want Copy As->Plain Text from the Edit menu rather than a regular copy.

Comment: I used but {0.4, 0.286, 0.000254207} and {0.4, 0.034, 0.457662} they don't have same digits in the third number!!!

Comment: Your problem is because you are using machine-precision numbers. Read: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html

Comment: I used `Chop[dm, 10^-2], Chop[t, 10^-4],Chop[n, 10^-5]` Also I used `SetPrecision[n,4]` but I did not get a good desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Target is **to save them for being protected from unintentional events** I propose a different strategy, but check first,

[NumberForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html)

[NumberMarks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberMarks.html)

[Machine‐Precision Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html)

```
vals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {12, 3}]
```

NB copied as **Plain Text**

> {{0.768526,0.981104,-0.384388},{0.177151,0.378702,0.537739},{0.338071,0.100119,0.548224},{-0.374293,0.472408,-0.102244},{-0.217492,0.445251,-0.913405},{-0.465784,-0.00326553,0.756313},{0.416133,-0.669428,0.371823},{0.906655,-0.0154896,-0.0677684},{0.31712,0.991293,-0.369311},{0.107006,-0.600543,0.987313},{0.77811,-0.566304,0.745197},{-0.242659,-0.987115,-0.368953}}

```
first = SetPrecision[vals, 4]
```

> {{0.7685,0.9811,-0.3844},{0.1772,0.3787,0.5377},{0.3381,0.1001,0.5482},{-0.3743,0.4724,-0.1022},{-0.2175,0.4453,-0.9134},{-0.4658,-0.003266,0.7563},{0.4161,-0.6694,0.3718},{0.9067,-0.01549,-0.06777},{0.3171,0.9913,-0.3693},{0.1070,-0.6005,0.9873},{0.7781,-0.5663,0.7452},{-0.2427,-0.9871,-0.3690}}

```
second = NumberForm[vals, 2]
```

> {{0.77,0.98,-0.38},{0.18,0.38,0.54},{0.34,0.1,0.55},{-0.37,0.47,-0.1},{-0.22,0.45,-0.91},{-0.47,-0.0033,0.76},{0.42,-0.67,0.37},{0.91,-0.015,-0.068},{0.32,0.99,-0.37},{0.11,-0.6,0.99},{0.78,-0.57,0.75},{-0.24,-0.99,-0.37}}

```
first
```

> {{0.7685,0.9811,-0.3844},{0.1772,0.3787,0.5377},{0.3381,0.1001,0.5482},{-0.3743,0.4724,-0.1022},{-0.2175,0.4453,-0.9134},{-0.4658,-0.003266,0.7563},{0.4161,-0.6694,0.3718},{0.9067,-0.01549,-0.06777},{0.3171,0.9913,-0.3693},{0.1070,-0.6005,0.9873},{0.7781,-0.5663,0.7452},{-0.2427,-0.9871,-0.3690}}

```
second
```

> {{0.77,0.98,-0.38},{0.18,0.38,0.54},{0.34,0.1,0.55},{-0.37,0.47,-0.1},{-0.22,0.45,-0.91},{-0.47,-0.0033,0.76},{0.42,-0.67,0.37},{0.91,-0.015,-0.068},{0.32,0.99,-0.37},{0.11,-0.6,0.99},{0.78,-0.57,0.75},{-0.24,-0.99,-0.37}}

Export you values to

```
Export["00_1.m", vals]
```

> 00_1.m

Get your values

```
<< "00_1.m"
```

> {{0.768526,0.981104,-0.384388},{0.177151,0.378702,0.537739},{0.338071,0.100119,0.548224},{-0.374293,0.472408,-0.102244},{-0.217492,0.445251,-0.913405},{-0.465784,-0.00326553,0.756313},{0.416133,-0.669428,0.371823},{0.906655,-0.0154896,-0.0677684},{0.31712,0.991293,-0.369311},{0.107006,-0.600543,0.987313},{0.77811,-0.566304,0.745197},{-0.242659,-0.987115,-0.368953}}

And format your Data

> {{0.77,0.98,-0.38},{0.18,0.38,0.54},{0.34,0.1,0.55},{-0.37,0.47,-0.1},{-0.22,0.45,-0.91},{-0.47,-0.0033,0.76},{0.42,-0.67,0.37},{0.91,-0.015,-0.068},{0.32,0.99,-0.37},{0.11,-0.6,0.99},{0.78,-0.57,0.75},{-0.24,-0.99,-0.37}}

Comment: `SetPrecision` does not actually change values but hides the additional digits from the user. For instance, copying and pasting the output of `SetPrecision[1./7, 5]` (within _Mathematica_) yields ``0.14285714285714284921269268124888185412`5.``, not `0.14286`. I believe OP's problem is on copying/pasting the output, not the outputs themselves. (If this were the case, `Chop` would have worked`)

Comment: @JHM, the idea is not to get set with precision but beeing flexible to use the command on data. Therefore, the way with the export.

Comment: @Louis, The way is wonderful. It is so easy to keep data. Thans

Comment: @Louis Ah, yep. I misunderstood the question. Also, @Irreversible , if you want to assign a variable to the exported/imported values you could do `vals = << "00_1.m"`.

Comment: I must practically try to my data. Again thanks so much

Comment: @Irreversible Please, with pleasure, otherwise you can put a new question.